# How to make the minimum width of the page by using Susy?

Tags: css, sass, susy

How to make the minimum width of the page by using Susy? For example:

```
body {
   min-width: 320px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what u want, but maybe you can [override the container settings like so](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/susyone/#container-override-settings)

```
// $container-width: <length> | <boolean>;
$container-width: false;
```

- `<length>: Length in em, px, %, etc.`
- `<boolean>: True or false.`

Comment: My main goal to set min-width of body to 320px. So when web page meet device smaller than 320x480 page dont break. Sorry for bad english :)

Comment: Susy is meant to be good for mobile devices. If your page breaks, you're probably using it wrong. Setting a minimal-width will only result in having to scroll horizontally on a mobile device, that's absolutely NOT user friendly. Try to fix your css all the way, set a viewpoint and make use of [media queries like these (just a random website)](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)

Comment: Perhaps the root of my problems that I don't use mobile first approach...

Comment: But how to set my layout when page seas device smaller then 320x480 with mobile first approach?

Comment: Put your css in the media query blocks.. use the link I gave you, and study a bit.

Comment: Ok, I will.Thank you very much :) !

Comment: Glad I could help pointing you in the right direction :).